# How to monitor playback position in exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am struggling to find a way to create a thread to monitor the playbackPosition in Exoplayer app.

In the following code, a simple task I need is to log the position parameter after every 1000ms by overriding the **onIsPlayingChanged** function. But I understand this happens only once and if the app state changes, however, to make this continuous, I think I should create a thread. Please let me know how can I achieve this. 
As you can see, the commented code is the one I tried but it is definitely not right.

```java
private class PlaybackStateListener implements Player.EventListener{

    @Override
    public void onIsPlayingChanged(boolean isPlaying) {
     //TODO: Add handler to poll the playback position continuously.
      /* if(isPlaying){
        HandlerCompat.
                postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                    long positionParam = playbackPosition;
                  }
                });
        }*/

      if (isPlaying) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Playing position is " + playbackPosition);
      } else {
        // Not playing because playback is paused, ended, suppressed, or the player
        // is buffering, stopped or failed. Check player.getPlaybackState,
        // player.getPlayWhenReady, player.getPlaybackError and
        // player.getPlaybackSuppressionReason for details.
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following piece of code can be used to resolve such issue using handler postDelayed method.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//My code
}
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
    public void run() {
    playbackPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
    send(playbackPosition);   //Function to update position
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); //1000ms frequency of updates.
    }
}, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Kotlin Coroutines way

```
private fun pollCurrentDuration() = flow {
        while (player.currentPosition + DURATION_OFFSET <= player.duration) {
            emit(player.currentPosition + DURATION_OFFSET)
            delay(DEFAULT_DELAY_MS)
        }
    }.conflate()
```

Comment: This won't actually work because you are accessing exoplayer from a different thread other than `main`. https://exoplayer.dev/issues/player-accessed-on-wrong-thread

Comment: @BrookMG it's ok if you use the Dispatchers.Main context:
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        pollCurrentDuration(exoPlayer).collect() { value -> println(value) }
                    }